# Connect to remote dbf file with lazarus on linux

Tags: linux, delphi, dbf, visual-foxpro

I need migrate a windows application made with delphi xe3 to a linux platform using Lazarus.
This application connect to dbf files hosted on a windows server 2008.

I'm trying to connect tdbf component to the server but i can't.
The documentation does not tell anything about remote connections.

Can you recommend me some other options to do that?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is the example code? What error messages do you get?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/d3Y2D5qu i tried with the propertie "filePath" , I can not find another property with which to accomplish the connection

Comment: you can try to use backslashes in UNC path to dbf files, like this \\192.160.90.100\F\shared-folder, and, of course, you must check you permissions on target folder at server. maybe dbf files require exclusive access to work with it. FoxPro not seem to be network DBMS.

Comment: Thanks @Kutsoff . Yes I tried with all this [http://goo.gl/xZoxG5](http://goo.gl/xZoxG5) . The shared folder in the server have the correct permissions.

Comment: try to use Network Drive pointed to you shared folder. on client PC press Win+R and type "net use X \\192.160.90.100\F\shared-folder", after this you will be see a X drive in windows explorer and dbf file path can use x:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dbf1.filePath := '192.160.90.100:/F/shared-folder';` This looks like an NFS path which I don't believe `TDBF` supports. You will need to mount the relevant folder containing your DBF files on your local file system for `TDBF` to be able to access it properly.

However, I would strongly recommend you migrate your application away from DBF files and to a proper SQL-based client/server DBMS like Firebird, mySQL or PostgreSQL. There really is no valid reason for using 25+ year old desktop databases nowadays.

Comment: Yes! i totally agree with you, but unfortunately i've work with old technology right now. I think the option of mount the folder is the only way, and the best, to do what i wanna do. Thanks @Andy_D